# FOSUserBundle not sending registration email

Tags: email, registration, fosuserbundle, symfony

I have found a few topics related to the same issues, but the solution for them was a miss-configuration of the smtp settings.

I am using symfony 3.0 and latest FOSUserBundle. My config settings are:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    resetting:
        email:
            template: email/password_resetting.email.twig
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            from_email:
                address:        registration@site.com
                sender_name:    'Our Team'


swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    port:      "%mailer_port%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

I am able to send other emails from the same project, using the same  swiftmailer settings.
  I have checked the web developer tool and the email is prepared for sending 
[Web profiler - email area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKf0x.png)
  The registration email is not received in the inbox or spam folders.

Could you let me know if I have missed anything in the configuration files that prevents the registration email from being sent?

Thanks,
Lucia

Comment: I found a solution for my problem. The registration email address had to be the same as the one used for the swiftmailer username settings. Having it set to a different email address did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem. The registration email address had to be the same as the one used for the swiftmailer username settings. Having it set to a different email address did not work for me.